# How to use DLL functions within a non-modifiable source code?

Tags: c++, dll, overloading

I am a noob so please, don't hesitate to elaborate and explain what you mean. 
I am currently working on a third-party source code in c++, for which I am developping plugins, and that I don't want to modify for obvious reasons (new version coming out, sharability and so on). The autors of the third party code have prepared for the use of plugins by using an external instruction file, in which parameters and such are being specified with keywords. The object creation reads the keywords in the instruction, and finds in the factory if the keyword has been declared. If so, it calls the specified constructor, otherwise call default constructor. 
Until now I only had to deal with such factory-related objects, so I created dlls that define sub-classes and call the associated constructor using the instruction file. Then, I could use overloaded or overriden functions defined in the dll in the rest of the main program (as the object constructed was of the sub-class).

The reason for this topic is that I don't want to touch the initial source code, and still want to overload/override a function used within the main program, but it is not defined in a factory-related object. This is the main program declaration of the function, within the TrajectoryLoader class:

```
namespace NAF {
    class TrajectoryLoader : public Object {
    public:
        NAF_CORE_API TrajectoryLoader() { _good = false; }
        NAF_CORE_API virtual ~TrajectoryLoader() {}
        NAF_CORE_API virtual bool LoadTrajectory(std::string filename);
        NAF_OBJ_DECLARES(TrajectoryLoader)
    private:
        CSVRange _range;
        bool _good;
    };

}
```

The one that I want to overload/override is NAF_CORE_API virtual bool LoadTrajectory, which loads and parses and argument file to create a "trajectory" object to be used later. I need to allow for different formats of files, as it only gets a specific writting syntax rigth now.

I tought I could create a sub-class for TrajectoryLoader and call the overloaded version of LoadTrajectory, but the main code calls LoadTrajectory like this:

```
traj = std::make_shared<TrajectoryLoader>();
traj->NAFSetName(id);
traj->LoadTrajectory(v);
```

with "v" the fullname of the file I want to load. Even with a sub-class defined, I expect that "traj" being from the parent class, Loadtrajectory would be the non-overriden function (I tested it as well).

The questions then are: Can I make this second piece of code call for an overloaded version of LoadTrajectory ? (I assume the answer to be no) and How can I make the main program (that I don't want to modify) call for functions from my own dll during execution ?

I hope that I am clear in my request, but I admit I only started C++ for this project, therefore I may have missed some simple tricks that would work. I looked on the internet for two days trying to find a way but didn't.

It is also possible that this is not possible to do, in which case I will have to find another way to make things work.

Thank you for your help, and sorry for the long post or if this is a duplicate, I may be missing technical term to find what I want.

With love,

Mortimer

edit: trying to clarify the question.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to pass parameters to your plug in when it is loaded?  Perhaps you can consult the authors of the host application about the best way to do that.  You are certainly on the wrong path here.

Comment: In fact I need to either 1. use a modified function in the main program or 2. pass along main program's parameters to my DLL process. Being able to do either of those would solve my problem, but I mainly want to know if it is doable, or if I am, as you said, on the wrong path (and maybe get a sense of the right direction).

Comment: Talk to the developers of the host application.  If you don't know what it's doing, I certainly don't.

Comment: I understand the main code, but I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible or not (i.e. to get a parent class call for an overriden function, or to "insert" calls to my dll's functions during the execution of the main code, without modifing the main code). I edited to remove confusing parts of the question.

Comment: I sincerely doubt it, no.  If the host is instantiating the object then only methods in that object will ever be called, virtual or otherwise.  Talk to the authors!!  They've probably faced this question before.  Don't keep battering away at a locked door.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer and your time :)

Comment: Pleasure.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically this snippet from the EXE:

traj = std::make_shared();
traj->NAFSetName(id);
traj->LoadTrajectory(v);

Since the compiler saw that snippet when it built the EXE, it knows that `LoadTrajectory` is `TrajectoryLoader::LoadTrajectory`. Instead of making an actual call, the compiler can *inline* the function. That means it takes the body of the function and inserts it where you'd expect the `CALL` assembly instruction to be.

Evn if this isn't done, the compiler will have inserted a direct call to exactly `TrajectoryLoader::LoadTrajectory`.

Now at runtime the OS is aware of *some* function calls, where the compiler (or programmer) has indicated that the calls are across DLL's.  That's how the plugin mechanism works here. But all function calls that are internal to an EXE or DLL are invisible to the OS.